# How to Submit an iOS app to the App Store (iTunes Connect) using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

When you're done coding your app, if I'm right, you upload your build to iTunes Connect using either Xcode or Application Loader.

What I'm asking is:
**How exactly would I go about submitting my build to iTunes Connect using Xcode (6.3.2)?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<sup>This post has been updated for 2019's new AppStore Connect and Xcode 10.</sup>

---

Here is a "short" guide for what to do:

**In [Apple's Member Center](http://developer.apple.com/membercenter):**

1. log in using your developer account's AppleID
2. navigate to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
3. choose Certificates
4. download / create iOS Certificates for *iOS Distribution* and *iOS Development*
5. navigate to *Provisioning Profiles*
6. download / create Provisioning Profiles for *iOS Distribution* and *iOS Development*

**In [AppStore Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com):**

1. log in using your developer account's AppleID
2. navigate to *My Apps*
3. in the top left corner press +
4. fill in all the data it asks for

**In Finder:**

1. navigate to your previously downloaded certificates and provisioning profiles
2. double-click them
3. enter passwords if necessary
4. close KeyChain if it popped up

**In Xcode:**

1. open your project
2. in the top left corner tap on the project file
3. under *Identity* set the version & build numbers
4. for *Signing*, check *Automatically manage signing*
5. ...then select your team as
6. select *Generic iOS Device* or a connected device under *Schemes*
7. use <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to build your project
8. in the status bar, find *Product* and select *Archive*. This will take a while to archive your project and eventually bring up the *Archives* section of xcode's Organizer
9. click *Disrtibute App*
10. follow the steps to complete the process. You should only have to press *Next* a few times. If everything goes well, the progress will say something like *uploading binary*.
11. Wait until Xcode has successfully uploaded the binary to AppStore Connect. Then proceed with the steps below.

**Back in AppStore Connect:**

1. log in using your developer account's AppleID
2. navigate to *My Apps*
3. select your app
4. scroll down and find *Build*
5. there it should show your build you just uploaded via Xcode, select it if necessary

   - note that the build might not be selectable just yet. It needs to complete processing first. This usually takes about an hour.
6. fill in all data required

   - note If you want to manually release your app after it's reviewed select that option under Version Release, otherwise skip this
7. next, press *Submit For Review*
8. answer the questions they ask

...

9. When the review is finished you can either release it manually to the AppStore or it will automatically do that depending on what you selected in step 6.

   - Review for new apps usually takes about a week, but it may vary. Updates will take a few days only
   - After release its status will be *Processing for App Store*, that may take about half an hour
   - The status will then change to *Ready for Sale* which effectively means, users can now download your app