# Xcode: Upload to App Store greyed out, but paid $99

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, developer-tools

I'm still new to programming and this is my first ever app to be posted onto the AppStore.
I've seen a few tutorials on how to do it and followed almost all the steps. But right now I'm stuck at this point and have no clue where to go from here. I've already paid the $99 to Apple and obtained the certificates, appID and profiles...
But its all futile. I'm looking for help if possible, and thank you very much :/

[image: Image for problem]

edit: I managed to get it to work by downloading the provisioning profile and opening it. Which then made all these buttons available to me. It sometimes becomes greyed out again, but as long as I open the provisioning profile again, it works. So I'm guessing thats the solution.

Comment: Check out my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30961923/3397217).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image seems like you haven't add your developer account to XCODE and haven't set the provisioning profile.

XCODE > Preferences > Accounts and add your account & click download all profiles.

Then you have to follow 7th step of the below article which has the all needed informations and steps you want to upload your app to the app store. Please make sure to complete each and every step carefully. It's not hard just few clicks.

[How to submit an app to app store](https://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-submit-an-app-to-the-app-store/)

Comment: @Kendrew If the answer was correct, then _accept_ it (click the checkmark at the left so that it is green).